# Creating a pie-chart (superimposed) with data points and connections to the center of the circle and between data points

Tags: html, data-visualization, charts, user-interface

What software packages/libraries can I use to develop the UI described below?  I am familiar with angularjs. I am experienced in back-end programming.
This is my foray into front-end UI development.

Purpose:

- Create a pie chart with data points inside of each slice of the pie.
- Display an image at the center of the circle (pie chart).
- The data points can be images or text.
- Upon hovering over the data point, it should display more information about it.
- The data points are connected to the center image using bold or dotted lines.
- The data points may be connected to each other using bold or dotted lines.

Parameters that can change are:

1. Number of slices in the pie.
2. Number of data points.
3. Thickness of the lines.
4. Type of lines (dotted etc.)
5. Images instead of/in addition to text for the data points.

Attached is a mockup of what I am trying to accomplish.  Thanks in advance.

[image: example mockup]

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Chart for JavaScript](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejchart) supports creating Pie charts and customizations can be done on the Pie chart to achieve your requirement.

[Example](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/jgsccb4t)

[image: Pie Chart with overlay]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Thank you! I will check out the community license.